# The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it

Tags: java, androidx

İ'm new to İT.This mıstake torments me the second day. Tried with Firebase ,but doesn't help.İ downloaded the goodle-servise.json and left in file app. Nothing helps.

```
Execution failed for task ':hello java:processDebugGoogleServices'. > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot
```

.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Rather than snippets of code, can you provide a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) reproducible example please?

Comment: DİD YOU İT MEAN  ?